# Change date of birth date format in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, frontend, validation

I want to change the validation for DOB field on create account page.

Currently the validation is in the format mm/dd/yyyy , I want to change the validation for that field to dd/mm/yyyy.

Can anybody tell me where is the validation code located. how to modify the validation rule for DOB field.

Answer (score 0):

In this file :

vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Widget/Dob.php

functions is

```
public function getDateFormat()
    {
        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormatWithLongYear();
        /** Escape RTL characters which are present in some locales and corrupt formatting */
        $escapedDateFormat = preg_replace('/[^MmDdYy\/\.\-]/', '', $dateFormat);

        return $escapedDateFormat;
    }
```

Write its after plugin and change dates format what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to amend the code to acheive this you can update the formatting for dates in magento by the following method

1. Log in the Magento 2 Admin
2. Click on the Store section on Admin sidebar.
3. Under the Setting, Go to Configuration
4. Expand the Catalog option and choose the catalog option
5. Set the date and time format to your prefered format and save

This should give you the result your after. you may need to redeploy your website

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Also you may need to flush the cache

```
bin/magento c:f
```

This should now give you the result your after

if the above does work the only other way would be to create an overwrite of Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob and amend the getFieldHtml and getHtmlExtraParams functions to replace your with your specific date format

Comment: Did not work Still the validation rule is same <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="" class="_has-datepicker mage-error" data-validate="{&quot;validate-date&quot;:{&quot;dateFormat&quot;:&quot;M\/d\/Y&quot;}}" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="dob-error">

Comment: have updated answer

Comment: @DavaGordan Did that too. public function getHtmlExtraParams()
    {
        $validators = [];
        if ($this->isRequired()) {
            $validators['required'] = true;
        }
        $validators['validate-date-au'] = "d/M/Y";
        return 'data-validate="' . $this->_escaper->escapeHtml(json_encode($validators)) . '"';
    } Still not working

Comment: did you also change getFieldHtml date_format

Comment: @DavaGordan. Yes, still getting error as Invalid date.

Comment: @DavaGordan Any idea what's missing?

Comment: @Nafisa after some digging i found that was an issue with the validation.js

Comment: @DavaGordan What issue? can u please explain?

Comment: have you found any solution?